Designing a reed switch circuit
I have been trying to design a door contact sensor. Almost 90% is completed, but I am confused about this reed switch circuit. The problem with the circuit is it is consuming too much current  I am designing for a battery-operated device, so if anyone have solutions for that circuit, please help me.

This circuit consumes 33uA  when the  reed switch is closed. Are there any other topologies that I can use?

Please [edit] your question and explain what else the switch is connected to. e.g., is it a microcontroller input? If so state the make, model and provide a datasheet link. Don't post additional information in the comments.

It should be consuming 5mA when the switch is closed - not 33uA.

use a 10 meg resistor, then it will consume 0.5 uA

Will the door be more often closed or open? Change the circuit to consume more current during the shorter state.

Assuming this is feeding a microcontroller input you can can feed the 1k resistor from a spare output rather than directly from the +5V supply. Then when measurement is required turn on the input, give it enough time to stabilise then read the switch input.
